# Python how to detect white image

Tags: image-processing, python

I am searching for python code or library to detect blank/white images like [png ,jpg ,bmp].

Answer (score 1):

Blank as in all pixels are white or an "empty" image?
For the first case, you can simply check if all the pixels are white by using something like `if np.sum(img == 255) == (number of element in image, i.e., width*heigth)`.

(Assuming it is a 8-bit grayscale image).

For the second case, you can open the image using openCV, PIL or matplotlib and then check the dimensions of the result.